# Is it possible to keep the inner html of a custom element?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, native-web-component

Using Custom Elements, I would like to style the elements inside the custom element, but when I define the element, everything besides the shadow dom disappears.

How do I move the content from the element to the shadow dom? I already have a wrapper element (`<div class="wrapper">`) inside the shadow, but trying to use

```
wrapper.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
```

doesn't work.

HTML

```
<site-card>
  <section title>
    ...
  </section>
  <section body>
    ...
  </section>
  <section actions>
    <button class="modern small">Action</button>
    <button class="modern small">Action 2</button>
  </section>
</site-card>
```

JS

```
"use strict";
class cardElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.setAttribute('class','wrapper');
        wrapper.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.textContent = ... /* CSS removed to shorten. */
        shadow.appendChild(style);
        shadow.appendChild(wrapper);
    };
};
customElements.define('site-card', cardElement);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include all relevant lines of code, its output and explain the expected result versus what you get.

Comment: @marekful Thanks! I have added the HTML and JS.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to control the CSS from outside of the custom element then just use `<slot>`. `<slot>` embeds the children into the slot but leaves CSS control to outside the element.

```js
class cardElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    var wrapper = document.createElement('slot');
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.textContent = `
    [title] {
      background-color: #060;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    [body] {
      background-color: #600;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    [actions] {
      background-color: #006;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    `;
    shadow.appendChild(style);
    shadow.appendChild(wrapper);
  };
};
customElements.define('site-card', cardElement);
```

```css
[title] {
  background-color: #0F0;
  color: #000;
}
[body] {
  background-color: #F00;
  color: #000;
}
[actions] {
  background-color: #00F;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<site-card>
  <section title>
    This is the title
  </section>
  <section body>
    This is the body
  </section>
  <section actions>
    <button class="modern small">Action</button>
    <button class="modern small">Action 2</button>
  </section>
</site-card>
```

If you want to control the CSS from inside the element then you need to migrate the children. But this can *not* be done in the constructor. [This section of the spec](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-element-conformance) explains the limitations on the constructor.

You need to move the children in the `connectedCallback`

```js
class cardElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this._wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.textContent = `
    [title] {
      background-color: #060;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    [body] {
      background-color: #600;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    [actions] {
      background-color: #006;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    `;
    shadow.appendChild(style);
    shadow.appendChild(this._wrapper);
  };
  
  connectedCallback() {
    while(this.firstElementChild) {
      this._wrapper.appendChild(this.firstElementChild);
    }
  }
};
customElements.define('site-card', cardElement);
```

```css
[title] {
  background-color: #0F0;
  color: #000;
}
[body] {
  background-color: #F00;
  color: #000;
}
[actions] {
  background-color: #00F;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<site-card>
  <section title>
    This is the title
  </section>
  <section body>
    This is the body
  </section>
  <section actions>
    <button class="modern small">Action</button>
    <button class="modern small">Action 2</button>
  </section>
</site-card>
```

> I would suggest avoiding using `innerHTML` since that will wipe out any event handlers, etc. that might already exist. It may actually be slower depending on the number of direct children. It could also mess up any children that may be custom elements.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You should do it a bit later, in `window.onload`:

```
class cardElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        var shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.setAttribute('class', 'wrapper');
        window.onload = () => {
            wrapper.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        };
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.textContent = ... /* CSS removed to shorten. */
        shadow.appendChild(style);
        shadow.appendChild(wrapper);
    }
};
customElements.define('site-card', cardElement);
```

Comment: `window.onload` may have already triggered if the component is created through JavaScript.