# How to keep original DOM children when attaching a shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

I have a root `div` element with two children:

```
<div id = "root">
  <div id="firstChild">FirstChild</div>
  <div id="secondChild">SecondChild</div>
</div>
```

I attach a `shadow DOM` to `root` and append another child to the shadow DOM. I would expect to see all three children:

```
ShadowChild
FirstChild
SecondChild
```

or

```
FirstChild
SecondChild
ShadowChild
```

However, attaching the shadow seems to hide the original children of the root `div`:

```
 ShadowChild
```

=>How can I keep/show the original children?

The following code example might require Chrome browser to support the method `attachShadow`:

```js
var root = document.getElementById('root')
var shadowRoot = root.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
var shadowChild = document.createElement('div');
shadowChild.innerText ='ShadowChild';
shadowRoot.appendChild(shadowChild);
```

```html
<div id = "root">
  <div id="firstChild">FirstChild</div>
  <div id="secondChild">SecondChild</div>
</div>
```

*Edit*

[Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#shadow-host) it says

> While the children of a shadow host do not generate boxes normally, they can be explicitly pulled into a shadow tree and forced to render normally. This is done by assigning the elements to a distribution list. An element with a distribution list is an insertion point.

=>How can I do so for a custom html element?

My use case is a custom tab folder that I want to use like

```
<treez-tab-folder id="root">
   <treez-tab title="First tab">
        <div id='firstContent'>First tab content</div>
    </treez-tab>

    <treez-tab title="Second tab">
        <div>Second tab content</div>
    </treez-tab>
</treez-tab-folder>
```

[image]

I create headers for the tabs in a shadow dom of `treez-tab-folder`, using the title attribute. The creation of the headers works, but the tabs can not be seen any more. I could copy the original `treez-tab` children to the shadow DOM. But what if another tab is dynamically added to the tab folder later?

```
d3.select("#root").append('treez-tab');
```

As already stated I would like to enable the rendering of the original children or automatically "redirect/proxy" the original children to the shadow DOM.

Related question, including the tab folder example without a shadow dom:

[How to target custom element (native web component) in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071186/how-to-target-custom-element-native-web-component-in-vue-js)

Not using a shadow DOM would have the drawback that the original `treez-tab-folder` includes additional DOM elements, possibly causing issues (e.g. with vue.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone wondering today: was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48777481/10256886).
Basically, a `<slot>` element to the shadow DOM.

```js
var root = document.getElementById('root')
var shadowRoot = root.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

var wrapper = document.createElement('slot');
shadowRoot.appendChild(wrapper);

var shadowChild = document.createElement('div');
shadowChild.innerText ='ShadowChild';
shadowRoot.appendChild(shadowChild);
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="firstChild">FirstChild</div>
  <div id="secondChild">SecondChild</div>
</div>
```